# Quero atualizar registro de uma tabela através de outro Banco de Dados com colunas iguais

Tags: sql

Quero atualizar a Coluna ordem_subclasse da Tabela Prod_serv, sendo que a referência são as colunas codigo da Tabela Prod_serv e codigo da Tabela SubClasses:

```
USE S9_Real
UPDATE Prod_Serv SET
Ordem_Subclasse = SC.ORDEM
FROM Prod_Serv PS
INNER JOIN S9_Real_MP2.DBO.Prod_Serv MP2PS ON PS.Codigo = MP2PS.Codigo
INNER JOIN S9_REAL_MP2.DBO.Subclasses MP2SC ON PS.Codigo = MP2PS.Codigo
INNER JOIN Subclasses SC ON SC.Codigo = MP2SC.Codigo
WHERE SC.Codigo = MP2SC.Codigo
```

Comment: qual é o banco de dados? adicione uma tag pra ajudar quem ler a sua pergunta. a princípio pode fazer um link entre os dois bancos de dados

Comment: O banco de dados  Origem é S9_Real_mp2 e Destino  S9_real.

Comment: não é isso, quero dizer se é `sql-server`, `mysql`, `oracle` etc

Comment: Desculpe, o banco é  sql-server 2012.

Comment: neste caso você precisa ligar os servidores através de um *link server*, dai pode fazer select/update de um servidor pra outro, algo como `update campo=select campo from servidor.dbo.tabela`